# Custom response from Tarantool + Nginx

Tags: nginx, tarantool, nginx-upstreams, tarantool-cartridge

Have instance: Nginx in DMZ with TNT_nginx_upstream_module + Tarantool Cartridge as API server.

When i have response with good result - it's 200 OK + JSON with data
How to set other response?

- 400 Bad Request
- 403 Forbidden
- 404 Not found
- 410 Gone
- 500 Internal Server Error
- 503 Service Unavailable

Comment: Question is not clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Tarantool Nginx upstream module has been designed to follow JSON RPC, not the generic HTTP. There is a way to return arbitrary results, using `rewrite_by_lua` in the `location` section. It looks like this:

```
location /api {
  default_type application/json;
  rewrite_by_lua '
    ...
  ';
}
```

I'm not pasting the full snippet here, as it is quite long. You can look it up [here](https://github.com/tarantool/nginx_upstream_module/tree/82355b8a1276ad584308f3ee4cc6e6129ecb302f#http-headers-and-status).

In general, I would also advise you to not use the mentioned upstream module if you want a generic HTTP API. It is better to use the [HTTP server module](https://github.com/tarantool/http) written in Lua, and use Nginx as a regular reverse proxy. As a bonus, the Lua HTTP server comes on board of the [cartridge](https://github.com/tarantool/cartridge) module.